# Why network response is empty?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple task to do. I write name to input, next I click button and at the end I should show alert window with "hello name!" text, but my alert window is empty. I must do this using controller because later I'm going to use data from database. My code:

Controller

```
public JsonResult Getname(string name)
    {
        string text = "Hello " + name;
        return Json(text, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View

```
$("#btnGetText").click(function () {
    var name = $("#txtName").val();
    GetText(name);
});

function GetText(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetText","Home")',
        type: "GET",
        data: { "name": e },
        success: function (data) {

            alert("It works");
            alert(data);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
};
```

I think the problem is that I give ampty response, and I dont' know why.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRoUA.png)

Comment: I've no idea about asp.net, but shouldn't the action be Getname?

Comment: I changed it, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

In your js:

```
@Url.Action("GetText","Home")
```

But your controller name is `Getname`. It should be same. Change it on controller side or on js side.

Comment: @smile add `dataType: "json",` to your json request also

Comment: Still nothing :( I read many tutoriala with many other examples and none was working